# check if a list of dict is in ascending value and return the incorrect dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Dict below is just for example purpose:

```
a = [{'name':'sally','age':'31'},{'name':'greg','age':'30'},{'name':'josh','age':'32'},{'name':'bobby','age':'33',]
```

The order of the dict need to follow the age. So i need to check if the dict is in order or not and print their 'name' if the age not in order.

What i did so far was sorted out the list of dict according to their age (ascending)

```
sorted_age = sorted(a, key=lambda d: d['age'])
```

and compare both dict to see if they are equal or not.

```
 if a == sorted_age:
            continue
        else:
            print(False)
```

I need to print 'sally' and 'greg' as their age are not in order. and i dont know how to print their name

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip`:

```
[(a, b) for a, b in zip(data, data[1:]) if a['age'] > b['age']]
```

---

```
[({'name': 'sally', 'age': '31'}, {'name': 'greg', 'age': '30'})]
```

Answer (score -1):

Just iterate through the dicts:

```
for da, ds in zip(a, sorted_age):
    if da != ds:
        print(da['name'])
print('are not in order')
```

Comment: The downvote wasn't me, but I do notice that `'are not in order'` is printed whether there were any out of order entries or not.

Comment: Well I assumed you'd put that instead of `print(False)` when you already know `a != sorted_age`...